# Need to parse from xml to db2

Tags: xml, db2

I am trying to parse data from XML. I need the kasi tag

```
SELECT
    ID, woId, kasi, XMLNOTIFICATION, XMLPDARESPONSE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            CAST( XML2CLOB(xmlquery(
                'declare namespace ns2="http://www.it.ibm.com/namespaces/rsl/amm/wo/commonWO"; $XMLNOTIFICATION/ns2:woOut/woOutput/header/woId/text()'
            )) AS VARCHAR(100) ) AS WOID,
             CAST( XML2CLOB(xmlquery(
                'declare namespace ns2="http://www.it.ibm.com/namespaces/rsl/amm/wo/commonWO"; $XMLNOTIFICATION/ns2:woOut/woOutput/woExececutionResults/electricityMeterInstallation/additionalInstallationData/kapiKasi.kasi/text()'
--       /kasi/text()'
            )) AS VARCHAR(100) ) AS KASI,
            XMLNOTIFICATION, XMLPDARESPONSE
        FROM
            WOP.BUNDLE_WORK_ORDER
        WHERE
            XMLNOTIFICATION IS NOT NULL
        AND REFERENCEPREFIX = 1
        AND REFERENCENUMBER = ('561527801')
    )
WHERE
    WOID in ('EXT561527801')
```

xml file is as attached
[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You must use XMLCAST( XMLQUERY(...) AS VARCHAR(100) ) instead.

Comment: May be you need `XMLTABLE()` instead?

Comment: I need to return the data for the attribute kasi.. I tried also the @kasi as per below but it did not return nothing.

            CAST( XML2CLOB(xmlquery(
            'declare namespace ns2="http://www.it.ibm.com/namespaces/rsl/amm/wo/commonWO"; $XMLNOTIFICATION/ns2:woOut/woOutput/woExececutionResults/electricityMeterInstallation/additionalInstallationData/kapiKasi/@kasi/text()'
           )) AS VARCHAR(100) ) AS KASI,

Comment: I have managed to get the data from the element but could not get data from the attribute.
<additionalInstallationData>
          <tampering>false</tampering>
          <kapiKasi adktcom="true" adktdy="true" kasi="5" kapi="150" />

Comment: What version/platform of DB2? Have you tried XMLTABLE which is the recommended way?